# ProGuard, Parse Exception, NoSuchMethodError: android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard

My app runs correctly on release mode if I disable proguard. But whenever I enable proguard, it crashes. I have changed the proguard-project.txt accordingly.

Here is the log I got:

```
> 10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2016
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674):    at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Unknown Source)
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674):    at com.myapp.android.view.l.run(Unknown Source)
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674):    at com.parse.ParseRequest.newHttpClient(Unknown Source)
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674):    at com.parse.ParseRequest.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
10-17 08:31:42.705: E/AndroidRuntime(20674):    ... 3 more
```

Here is my config in proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class com.parse.**{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep public class android.net.**{ *; }
-dontwarn android.net.**
```

Answer (score 1):

I added two lines, and solved.

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
```